# Trying to center my nav bar and hamburger icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

So basically I have a nav bar that floats left. The page is responsive so that when the screen is below a certain size, the nav bar disappears (except the Home link) and a hamburger drop-down menu pops up on the right. What I'm trying to do is figure out how to make the navigation bar centered and have it completely disappear when the screen size is reduced and have the hamburger icon appear and become centered on the screen.

HTML:

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">  
<nav>

  <a href="home.html">Home</a>  
  <a href="history.html">History</a>  
  <a href="information.html">Information</a>  
  <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
  <a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
  <a href="exercises.html">Exercises</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> 
  <a href="links.html">Links</a>  
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>

</nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
background-color: #000000;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 2.25em;
margin-bottom: 1.25%; 
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
background-color: #2C3539;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for 
the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close 
the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
.topnav a.icon {
float: right;
display: block;
}
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the 
user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small 
screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive a.icon {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
.topnav.responsive a {
float: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when 
the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
} else {
    x.className = "topnav";
}
}
</script>
```

Any help in doing this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> Removing floats and display: block, and using inline-block may fix your problems

```
display: inline-block;
```

### Your new code:

```
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
background-color: #000000;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
display: inline-block;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 2.25em;
margin-bottom: 1.25%; 
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
background-color: #2C3539;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

:D

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the problem

Comment: You have remove float?

Comment: I managed to center it by using <ul> to turn the links in the nav bar into a list, but now the links don't disappear when the screen shrinks....